# If statement for cookie - WebMatrix/Razor

Tags: cookies, razor, webmatrix, setcookie

I have set a cookie that I want to use to populate a form, so that users don't need to keep filling out the same form (it's submitting an inquiry to owners of holiday villas).

I've got it working fine if the cookie is already set, but it errors out if there is no cookie set.

I'm guessing I'll need to use an "if" statement, but don't quite know how to write the code.

Here is the code that sets the cookie...

```
Response.Cookies["BookingEnquiry"]["ReqName"] = Request["BookingReqName"];
Response.Cookies["BookingEnquiry"]["ReqEmail"] = Request["BookingReqEmail"];
Response.Cookies["BookingEnquiry"]["ReqPhone"] = Request["BookingReqPhone"];
Response.Cookies["BookingEnquiry"]["NumAdults"] = Request["BookingNumAdults"];
Response.Cookies["BookingEnquiry"]["NumChildren"] = Request["BookingNumChildren"];
Response.Cookies["BookingEnquiry"]["ReqMessage"] = Request["BookingReqMessage"];
Response.Cookies["BookingEnquiry"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(4); 
}
```

Here are the variables that collect info from the cookie...

```
var reqname = Request.Cookies["BookingEnquiry"]["ReqName"];
var reqemail = Request.Cookies["BookingEnquiry"]["ReqEmail"];
var reqphone = Request.Cookies["BookingEnquiry"]["ReqPhone"];
var numadults = Request.Cookies["BookingEnquiry"]["NumAdults"];
var numchildren = Request.Cookies["BookingEnquiry"]["NumChildren"];
var reqmessage = Request.Cookies["BookingEnquiry"]["ReqMessage"];
```

and here is a sample input from the form...

```
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="BookingReqName" id="BookingReqName" placeholder="full name…" value="@reqname">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WebMatrix C#.net, I think you are looking for something like this:

```
if(Request["BookingReqName"] != null)
{
    Response.Cookies["BookingEnquiry"]["ReqName"] = Request["BookingReqName"];
}
else
{
    Response.Cookies["BookingReqName"] = ""; //<--Whatever default value you want (I've used an empty string here, so you, at least, won't get a null reference error).
}
```

Or you can use the same code as a one liner (to not clutter up your code, however this will decrease readability, obv.).

```
if(Request["BookingReqName"] != null){Response.Cookies["BookingEnquiry"]["ReqName"] = Request["BookingReqName"];}else{Response.Cookies["BookingReqName"] = ""; //<--Whatever default value you want (I've used an empty string here, so you, at least, won't get a null reference error).}
```

You'll just have to do that for all of your lines requesting cookie values.

The point is, though, that anything can go in the "else" block that helps you handle what to do when the cookie values have been cleared/expired (which you must always expect). You could redirect to a page that requests information from the user to reset any "forgotten" configurations, or, if you want to persist the data no matter what, consider storing these values in a database, instead, as those values won't clear/expire.

One last thing, if this doesn't help:

If you find yourself wondering what value to store in the cookie (the default value you wish to specify), because you need to know, right then and there, what it was supposed to have remembered, then I am afraid it is time to reconsider how you have structured the flow of data.

Sorry, but I have done that, once upon a time, only with Session variables, and it wasn't pretty :)

If you need any help with the best way(s) to transfer data between web pages, check this very helpful, concise link from Mike Brind's website:  http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/192/Transferring-Data-Between-ASP.NET-Web-Pages

Answer (score 0):

It should just be the following

```
  if(Request.Cookies["BookingEnquiry"] == null)
  {
     return; // <- if BookingEnquiry is null we end this routine
  }

   // Normal code flow here...
```

or something similar

Comment: here's the error i'm getting. it's saying "var reqname = Request.Cookies["BookingEnquiry"]["ReqName"]; - object reference not set

Comment: As you are checking the variable Request.Cookies["BookingEnquiry"] for null and returning if it is null, there is no else, you just carry on with your normal code below this section. (if it's null then you will skip the part of the code that has an error) - see Edit.

Comment: Expected a "{" but found a "return".  Block statements must be enclosed in "{" and "}".  You cannot use single-statement control-flow statements in CSHTML pages. For example, the following is not allowed:

Comment: Sorry too much time using python

Comment: @Gavin5511 I will say, as far as C#.net is concerned, there shouldn't be anything wrong with this code block working, except that a return statement in a cshtml page will stop all your running code, afaik, not carry on with code below this section.